# How to manipulate 2sxc/dnn search result titles?

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc, dnn9

Does anybody have any idea on how to manipulate 2sxc/dnn search result titles?

Something like si.Title ?

Becuase at the moment search results are showing the page title and not the post title.

```
si.QueryString = "details=" + article.UrlKey;

si.Title  = article.Title;
```

I tried the above code but it does not work.

2sxc doc: https://docs.2sxc.org/api/dot-net/ToSic.Sxc.Search.ISearchItem.html

Answer (score 0):

Hi @BondLookingForAnswers - welcome to StackOverflow :)

I'm not sure if DNN will prefer your title to the page title, but either way I suggest you check out the latest blog app (https://2sxc.org/en/apps/app/blog-app-v4), which customizes the search results, and see where that gets you.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the rapid response. I forgot to mention that I'm using DNN Sharp Search booster. I'll take a look at the blog app.